# Bluetooth mouse pairs, but doesn't work

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, microsoft

I'm trying to get my bluetooth mouse (Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Mouse) to work. I've got it paired and trusted using blueman-manager. But the device isn't recognized as a mouse, it is listed as "unknown".

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Any help would be great.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't have the drivers installed. Are you able to find any drivers online for that device?

Comment: Doesn't seem like there are, I checked the microsoft website but there aren't even windows drivers available. I've tried the mouse on my android phone, and it works instantly.

Answer (score 1):

In the file /usr/share/gnome-bluetooth/pin-code-database.xml add the line:

```
<device oui="DC:7E:AA:" type="mouse" name="Microsoft Designer Mouse" pin="0000"/>
```

just below the line:

```
<device oui="7C:1E:52:" type="mouse" name="Microsoft Touch Mouse" pin="0000"/>
```

---

Information about the bluetooth connections for bluez version 4 is stored
in files in directory /var/lib/bluetooth/.
The basic problem with 14.04 is that the link key may not be added to the
linkkeys file when the mouse is paired, so the connection is not really
complete.  The pairing (for version 4) should create entries in the "names"
and "trusts" files, and an entry with a link key in the
`/var/lib/bluetooth/<host bt addr>/linkkeys` file.  The mouse address entries
do get created in the "names" and "trusts" files, but not in the "linkkeys"
file IF IT IS NOT ALREADY PRESENT.   To fix the problem, add the line
yourself (even the example line with an improper hex key), and it should be
properly maintained in future pairings.

Example line:

C0:33:5E:01:8A:AC DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF 4 0

The file is root only rw, so either become root to edit or unprotect,
edit, reprotect it.

Bluez version 5 uses a totally different location:

> `/var/lib/bluetooth/<host bt addr>/<mouse address>/info`

and different file for storing the link and other information.